# .net MVC - Model builder looping performance overhead

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

I'm fairly new to MVC, but I understand the principle.

I'm concerned that sticking religiously to that principle will cause performance issues.

For example, in order to send the view only the data it needs to display, I need to:

- retrieve data from the DB
- in a model builder loop row by row through the dataset, formatting fields and placing them in the viewmodel
- Send this to the view which then needs to loop through the dataset row by row to display it.

In most cases there aren't that many rows in the data, but it's this requirement to loop through the dataset twice which concerns me. Are loop operations inherently slow? Repeating it twice seems crazy?

I would rather would rather compromise by putting formatting in the view than repeat a loop.

Is this best practice?  In a modern system is this loop repetition so insignificant that it can be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

> In a modern system is this loop repetition so insignificant that it
>   can be ignored

Most likely this is the case.

No loop iterations run at O(n).  They aren't inherently slow (assuming you don't have lots, I mean LOTS of records).  I would write the code with the double loop and test to see how slow it is.  This is most likely a micro optimization, and your code is more inefficient in other places.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I was wondering. Is there a difference in performance between code i.e String.Format in the view compared to the compiled class file? Or should there be no difference.

Comment: No, there should be no difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st point you can just issue a LINQ query to get your data. This is the easiest one.

For the 2nd point you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). It automagically maps your returned rows from the DB to instances of your `ViewModel` class. It can map collections/enumerables like [Lists and Arrays](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays).

For the 3rd point you can pass the `List<ViewModel>` returned by AutoMapper to a grid-like [WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). It will take care of presenting the data on the view while allowing you to page the data (return only the amount necessary to that page, instead of bringing all rows from the DB), sort the data and a lot more.

If you use this workflow you won't have to loop through your data in various places. The looping operations are still there when using AutoMapper and when the WebGrid processes the rows passed to it. They are just hidden from you. This makes you fell better. :) Loops are inherent to this kind of workflow but if you return only the necessary data (paged data), it won't put a penalty on the user experience.

Comment: For the first point I am returning data from a DB stored procedure. 2nd and 3rd - I really hate using 'automagic' things because you have no real idea what it's doing, or how well it's doing it - and to be honest I find all this stuff obfuscates things so much that the code becomes less understandable.  Maybe I'm just old fashioned though.